# How to convert a string into variable in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a json from API

```
    let a = [{"name": 'abc',"age": '23'},{"name": 'qwe',"age": '37'},{"name": 'wqewqe',"age": '27'}]
```

then I want to create a function to be called

```
public testing(data, variable){
  console.log('Second name : ', data[1].variable)
}
```

if i called

```
this.testing(a,'name');
```

the result should be

```
Second name : qwe
```

can anyone share to me how to do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general to we have two ways to [access a property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) of an object as shown below

- `someObject.prop`
- `someObject['prop']`

So, here when you want to access a property of an object by using a variable we can achieve this using bracket notation i.e., `obj[<variable>]` is the way.

Below is the example for the same.

```js
let a = [{"name": 'abc',"age": '23'},{"name": 'qwe',"age": '37'},{"name": 'wqewqe',"age": '27'}];

//Provided an option to pass index as well
const printPropValue = (data, index, variable) => data[index][variable];

console.log(printPropValue(a, 1, 'name'));
console.log(printPropValue(a, 0, 'age'));
//console.log(printPropValue(a, 4, 'name')); --> Will crash
```

In the above approach there are some corner scenarios that need to be handled such as if the object at that `index` could be `null` or `undefined`. There are multiple ways in order to tackle such scenarios,

- One way is to use [`Optional Chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

```js
let a = [{"name": 'abc',"age": '23'},{"name": 'qwe',"age": '37'},{"name": 'wqewqe',"age": '27'}];

//Provided an option to pass index as well
const printPropValue = (data, index, variable) => data[index]?.[variable];

console.log(printPropValue(a, 1, 'name'));
console.log(printPropValue(a, 0, 'age'));
console.log(printPropValue(a, 4, 'name'));
```

- Other way using `|| (OR operator)`

```js
let a = [{"name": 'abc',"age": '23'},{"name": 'qwe',"age": '37'},{"name": 'wqewqe',"age": '27'}];

//Provided an option to pass index as well
const printPropValue = (data, index, variable) => (data[index] || {})[variable];

console.log(printPropValue(a, 1, 'name'));
console.log(printPropValue(a, 0, 'age'));
console.log(printPropValue(a, 4, 'name'));
```